# Command sudo: not found

Tags: shell, docker, debian

When executing my init.sh I am calling the command:

`sudo bash ${INSTALLPATH}seafile.sh start`

Following this, the error:

`seafile_1_f2341d904d27 | /bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found`

occurs.

opening the directory "bin" and looking at "sh" it is just some unreadable charakters..

The dockerfile calling init.sh does this by:

```
 FROM debian
#FROM armv7/armhf-debian

MAINTAINER me

# install packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install sudo -y

RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
ca-certificates \
python2.7 \
python-setuptools \
python-imaging \
python-ldap \
python-urllib3 \
sqlite3 \
wget

# Copy scripts
ADD ./scripts /scripts

# set environment variables
ENV SERVER_NAME mdh-seafile
ENV SERVER_IP 127.0.0.1
ENV FILESERVER_PORT 8082
ENV SEAFILE_DIR /data
ENV SEAFILE_VERSION seafile-server-6.3.4
ENV INSTALLPATH /opt/seafile/${SEAFILE_VERSION}/

# clean for smaller image
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Volumes for persistent configuration
VOLUME /opt/seafile/

# added
COPY /opt/seafile/${SEAFILE_VERSION}/seafile.sh .
COPY /opt/seafile/${SEAFILE_VERSION}/seahub.sh .


# set entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT sudo bash /scripts/init.sh
```

Init.sh:

```
else
  # start seafile
  # whoami -> Output: root
  sudo bash ${INSTALLPATH}seafile.sh start
  sudo bash ${INSTALLPATH}seahub.sh start
  # keep seafile running in foreground to prevent docker container shutting down
  while true; do
    sudo tail -f /opt/seafile/logs/seafile.log
    sleep 10
  done

fi
```

I'm executing everything by calling `sudo bash install.sh` which is executing docker-compose file which links to the components.

The Docker-Compose:

```
version: '2'
services:

  db:
    #image: hypriot/rpi-mysql
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=###
    volumes:
    - /mnt/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql

  duply:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
      - /mnt/data:/mnt/data
      - ./webinterface:/var/www/html/MyDigitalHome
      - /mnt/guestbackup:/mnt/guestbackup/backup
      #- /mnt/usb-removable:/usb-removable
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "24:22"
    links:
      - db
  seafile:
    build: seafile/
    volumes:
      - ./seafile/config:/config
      - /mnt/data/seafile:/data
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      - SEAFILE_ADMIN=###@mydigitalhome.xy
      - SEAFILE_ADMIN_PW=###


  owncloud:
    build: owncloud/
    volumes:
      - /mnt/data/owncloud:/data
      - ./owncloud/config:/var/www/html/config
    ports:
      - "8090:80"
    links:
      - db:mysql
```

The current errors are:

```
ERROR: Service 'seafile' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder845725722/opt/seafile/seafile-server-6.3.4/seafile.sh: no such file or directory

Attaching to mdh_seafile_1_f2341d904d27, mdh_db_1_46bebe733124, mdh_duply_1_170a5db26129, mdh_owncloud_1_260c3a56f2a5
seafile_1_f2341d904d27 | bash: seafile.sh: No such file or directory
seafile_1_f2341d904d27 | bash: seahub.sh: No such file or directory
seafile_1_f2341d904d27 | tail: cannot open '/opt/seafile/logs/seafile.log' for reading: No such file or directory
seafile_1_f2341d904d27 | tail: no files remaining
```

Comment: Please share some more info about your problem. Are you root? `sudo` may not exist because you're root. May not even have bash. `sh` file is a binary one, so that is normal.

Comment: @samthegolden Without sudo I get the error: file not found.

Comment: can you share the first line of your Dockerfile also? the FROM line. So we can know if you are using Ubuntu, Alpine or another distro?

Comment: You're already root in the container, you do not need sudo.

Comment: @BMitch - without sudo I get the error: there is no such directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from `debian` image you need to install `sudo`, you can do it by adding `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install sudo -y` to the beginning of your Dockerfile. Then rebuild your image with `docker build .` and run the command again.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191612/discussion-on-answer-by-marcelo-command-sudo-not-found). Please make sure to [edit] the answer to reflect the outcome of the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are running this in docker.
you can add to your dockerfile

`RUN apt update && apt install -y sudo`

This should resolve your problem.

Comment: I Already did that. Sudo works perfectly fine anywhere else.